# DownloadManager not Showing Icon in Status Bar

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

My Download Manager is not showing a notification icon in the status bar. The notification is their when you open all notifications but the icon is absent in the status bar so people cant tell at a glance that the download has started. This isn't a problem on older devices, and only on android phones running android 9 pie.

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(youtubeDataModel.getUrl()));
    request.setDescription("Downloading " + simpleFileType + "...");
    request.setTitle(fileName);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadLocation + "/" + fileName + "." + fileExtension)));
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
```

I expected the status bar to show a little download icon, but on newer devices it doesnt

Answer (score 1):

Try changing request notification visibility to

```
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
```